# Making NextJS example app use 4 spaces in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, tabs, tab-size

I am using the latest version of NextJS and the latest version of VS Code. In the Learn NextJS Getting Started section, you download the example using `npm` to get the example to learn from:

```
npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-dashboard --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/main/dashboard/starter-example"
```

I have tried SO, google and AI to try and get the 2 spaces to change to 4 spaces on Save. I have setup all the tabSize indent spaces in Settings and all the config files. The IDE on the button continues to say `Spaces: 2` and I do not know why this does not switch.

I am NOT using neither ESLint nor Prettier extensions or any other formatting extensions. How do I fix this?

Comment: After changing the spaces setting run "Format Document" on mac its: Option + Shift + F or right click on the document and in the menu hit "Format Document"